# How to interpret DCC GARCH alpha and beta (dcca1 and dccb1 in R)

Tags: multivariate-analysis, interpretation, garch, volatility

I have just run a DCC GARCH model in R and am trying to interpret the output. I have run the model with 3 time series. I know that alpha and beta tell about the short- and long-term spillover effect. However, I only get one `dcca1` and `dccb1` even though the values of `dcca1` and `dccb1` should be different for the different time series. So what do `dcca1` and `dccb1` tell me?

[image: This is the output]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, most of your interpretations are mistaken.

1. DCC model does not allow for volatility spillovers. If you want a model that does, consider e.g. the BEKK model.
2. `dcca1` and `dccb1` are the two parameters of the DCC equation that show the relative weights of standardized errors at time $t-1$ (`dcca1`) and the conditional correlation matrix at time $t-1$ (`dccb1`). There are no other parameters specific to the DCC. The other parameters you see in the R output are from the individual conditional mean equations (the ones ending with `mu`) and the conditional variance equations due to GARCH (the ones ending with `omega`, `alpha1` and `beta1`). For more details, see p. 3-5 of the [`rmgarch` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmgarch/vignettes/The_rmgarch_models.pdf).